# Magento 2.3.4 image save error

Tags: magento2, image, bug, vendor

After updated Magento to v2.3.4

> getimagesize('/var/www/project...') called at
> [vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-synchronization/Model/CreateAssetFromFile.php:78]

> Magento\MediaGallerySynchronization\Model\CreateAssetFromFile->execute(&SplFileInfo#000000002a784b8c00000000625dafb8#) called at [vendor/magento/module-media-gallery-integration/Plugin/SaveBaseCategoryImageInformation.php:94]

When i use **$this->imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($image, true)** [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ImageUploader.php] method;

How i can fix it is?